# How to find the distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Random variable X is uniformly distributed over the interval [0,1]. $Y = -ln(X)$.I need to find the distribution function for $Y$. So i did this:

$$P(Y \leq x)= P(-ln(X) \leq x) = P(ln(X) \geq -x) = 1 - P(X \leq e^{-x}) = 1 - e^{-x}$$

So distribution function is $1 - e^{-x}$? Is it correct? How to find intervals for it? How to find Expected value for it? Its and integral $\int_0^1 \frac{x}{e^{x}} dx$ but i can't find it

Comment: Yes. The domain of $Y$ is $[0,\infty)$ since $X$ in $[0,1]$ and $-ln([0,1])=[0,\infty)$. This is exponential distribution so the expectations and everything are well-known for it (integral is until $\infty$, not $1$).

Comment: To be more precise, the cumulative distribution function is $1-e^{-x}$. The probability distribution function is $e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 1):

The limits of the integral are now $0$ to $\infty$, because you've changed the density function and it must integrate to 1. Note that $Y$ can now take on values that are between $\lim_{x \rightarrow0}-ln(x) = +\infty$ on the one hand, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow1}-ln(x) = 0$ on the other. So you should rewrite your integral to reflect this, and it will integrate to 1.

$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}dx=1$

The expected value is just $\int_0^\infty x \cdot e^{-x}dx=1$